# Output JAXB short form tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am writing a program which currently outputs XML in this format:

```
<Id></Id>
```

However, I would prefer to have the output be like this:

```
<Id/>
```

I understand other programs that read XML won't care about the difference and that's fine...but I have a specific requirement to have the output in the latter format. I have searched through the JAXB API and could not find anything.

I have tried making the objects null, but that makes the node disappear. I have set it to null and made the element `nillable=true`, but that does not give the desired result.

The former output happens when you set the element with an empty string.

Does anyone know of a solution within JAXB to output short form elements?

Example code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyClassType", propOrder = {
    "id"
//....
})
public class MyClassType 
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Id", required = true)
    protected String id;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `<myNode>`? If so, try annotating the corresponding getter/attribute (depending on how you define your `@XmlAccessorType`) with `@XmlAttribute`.

Comment: @Turing85 The `@XmlAccessorType` is `XmlAccessType.FIELD`, and all member fields in the class are `@XmlElement`.